# How can I get an element's ID value with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there another way to get an DOM element's ID?

```
element.getAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Yes you can just use the [`.id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id) of the [dom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element), for example:

```
myDOMElement.id
```

Or, something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  alert(inputs[i].id);
}
```

Comment: @Rana - Yup, it's a DOM element property, and all specific elements inherit from the basic dom element, so they have the property :)

Comment: Be weary of this because `myDOMElement.id` can also return a child element with the id or name of 'id'. As seen here [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yY4xz/1/)

Answer (score 28):

Yes you can simply say:

```
function getID(oObject) 
{
    var id = oObject.id;
    alert("This object's ID attribute is set to \"" + id + "\"."); 
}
```

Check this out:
[**ID Attribute | id Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533880(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 21):

This would work too:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].id
```

(If element where the 1st paragraph in your document)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE (before IE9).

Comment: It was a mistake. Meant 'getElementByTagName' for dealing with a tag

Answer (score 6):

Super Easy Way is

```
  $('.CheckBxMSG').each(function () {
            var ChkBxMsgId;
            ChkBxMsgId = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(ChkBxMsgId);
        });
```

Tell me if this helps

Answer (score 5):

In events handler you can get id as follows

```js
function show(btn) {
  console.log('Button id:',btn.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="myButtonId" onclick="show(this)">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As bhattamer has commented:

> Be weary of this because myDOMElement.id can also return a child element with the id or name of 'id'

You need to check if the property "id" is a string to avoid getting a child element.

```
const getIdFromDomObj = function(domObj){
   const { id } = domObj;
   const isIdString = typeof id  === 'string';
   
   if(!isIdString) return;
   return id;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets and alerts the id of the element with the id "ele".

```
var id = document.getElementById("ele").id;
alert("ID: " + id);
```

Comment: if you know id, what is the need of this lines?

Comment: For illustrative purposes. Code doesn't always have to be real.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
console.log(id.id)
```

```html
<p id="id">
```

Answer (score -6):

Yes. You can get an element by its ID by calling `document.getElementById`. It will return an element node if found, and `null` otherwise:

```
var x = document.getElementById("elementid");   // Get the element with id="elementid"
x.style.color = "green";                        // Change the color of the element
```