# Make $(this) ID in class

Tags: jquery, class, this

I'm trying to set the `this` of which is an ID to the same string but in class.

For example:

```
$("#FirstBox").click(function () {
    $('.FirstBox').trigger('click');
});
```

Instead of typing `.FirstBox`, how can I set a variable so it's `$(this)` in class?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ruHgQ/

Comment: @SLaks - That's absolutely fantastic. `;)`

Comment: Note, don't have `.FirstBox` in `#FirstBox` or else you may end up in an endless loop (with both firing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get an element's id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id)

Comment: I am bursting with curiosity as to why you would want to do this. Something is an ID because it is unique; so they often have unique names. Taking a unique name and using it as a class will cause endless problems for any use case I can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.' + this.id)
```

Comment: @Slaks hi slaks, can I do the opposite? From class to div? I tried $('.' + this.class) but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast: `this.className`.  That assumes it only has one class.

Comment: @SLaks Wow really cool. How can I say without class btn ?. Because my selector has 2 classes so I'd like to say get the class of which not '.btn'. This is what I currently have: console.log('#' + this.className);

Comment: `this.className.replace(/\s*\bbtn\b\s*/, '')`

Comment: I would never find that. Thank you sir