# Very simple javascript request. Grab element ID

Tags: javascript

I have an element that I'm grabbing the value, thus:

```
var text = form1.elements[i].value;
```

What I want to know is if I can grab form1.elements[i].value's ID somehow.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var id = form1.elements[i].id;
```