# How to set text of div to its Id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

what I am trying to achieve is set the text of a div tag to the name if its ID from javascript. I have tried this;

```
 mydiv.getElementsByClassName("divDesign").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("divDesign").getElementById;
```

However, this returns `undefined` in the div tag instead of writing its id.

Comment: `getElementById` need a parameter, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id

Comment: If you want to get id you should use `.id` and not `.getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaAcharki that did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

### Using `getAttribute()` method:

---

*For the **first** div with `ClassName = 'divDesign'`:*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign')[0].getAttribute('id');
```

---

*For **all** divs with `ClassName = 'divDesign'`:*

```js
var mydivs = document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign');

for (var index = 0; index < mydivs.length; index++) {
  mydivs[index].innerHTML = mydivs[index].getAttribute('id');
}
```

```html
<div class="divDesign" id="someId"></div>
```

### Using `id()` property:

---

*For the **first** div with `ClassName = 'divDesign'`:*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign')[0].id;
```

---

*For **all** divs with `ClassName = 'divDesign'`:*

```js
var mydivs = document.getElementsByClassName('divDesign');

for (var index = 0; index < mydivs.length; index++) {
  mydivs[index].innerHTML = mydivs[index].id;
}
```

```html
<div class="divDesign" id="someId"></div>
```

Documentation:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to specify an index of the element as `document.getElementsByClassName("divDesign")` returns a nodes list.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("divDesign")[0].innerHTML = 
    document.getElementsByClassName("divDesign")[0].id;
```

```html
<div class="divDesign" id="iAmAnId"></div>
```