# JavaScript: If condition based on div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, web-applications

I'm making a web app for a school project and I'm creating a function for a click event on my ".tile" class. Inside the tile class I have 7 tile IDs; "#tile1", "#tile2" etc. I want to make an 'if' condition to check the ID of the tile clicked e.g. if (ID == "#tile2") {}. Is something like this possible or do I need to make functions for each individual tile? The rest of the function is fine I only need help with the if statement. Sorry if this is really easy I'm fairly new.

Comment: You can use a common method, Show the event handler code

Comment: Yes it is possible, and you are on the right track, so i suggest you give it a go and try to make it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get an element's id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id)

Comment: you can get the current element attribute using att = $(this).attr('id'); if(att=== 'tile1'){ }elseif(att=== 'tile2'){...} ..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can do :

```
$('.tile').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id === 'tile2'){
       // do smthing
    } else if(id === 'tile3'){

    } ...
});
```

Where $(this) is the clicked element

You could also use a switch case to switch between your id's. See the doc https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the click event listener on the class `.tile` and get the "clicked" tile's id by `$(this).attr('id')`, please see follow:

```js
$(".tile").click(function(){
  let id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("Clicked on div: " + id);
  if(id === "tile3")
    console.log("Yes, it's the third");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>What's the third?</p>
<div id="tile1" class="tile">tile 1</div>
<div id="tile2" class="tile">tile 2</div>
<div id="tile3" class="tile">tile 3</div>
<div id="tile4" class="tile">tile 4</div>
<div id="tile5" class="tile">tile 5</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.