# Remember element position when updating innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I receive an element through a function which I then want to re-target after updating the parent's innerHTML by replacing certain occurrences in it.

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```js
function update(child){
  child.parentNode.innerHTML = child.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(/Stuff/, 'Things');
  child.innerHTML = 'More stuff again.';
  console.log(child);
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='random things'></div>
  <br/>
  Stuff.
  <div id='child'>
    More stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see here, the child's `innerHTML` is correctly updated in the console, but not on the page. How can I target the correct element or remember the element's previous position after updating the parent's `innerHTML`?

**I don't know the exact position of the element, so I can't prepend or append it.**

Comment: `child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML + ' again.';` or `child.innerHTML += ' again.';`

Comment: @Alex No no, you're not getting the point, that was just an example.

Comment: You want to over-write the entire div?

Comment: @Alex that will not update the HTML

Comment: Rather than setting the innerHTML and recreating everything, what you really want to do is inject the new text nodes or whatever, so existing stuff remains

Comment: @Alec I know, that was from top of my head/

Comment: @Alex I'm overwriting the the parent div, so updating the innerHTML wouldn't work anymore, as stated in the question.

Comment: @Taplar I have thought of that, but I'm doing something specific that doesn't allow me to do something like that.

Comment: What limitations are keeping you from injecting text nodes?  Injecting elements is core javascript.

Comment: @Pete How would I know how the child variable is set when it's passed as a function parameter?

Comment: yeah, I'm out, we keep answering based on what you show us but your saying what you're showing is not correct so I'm not going round in circles...

Comment: I have said that the child variable is passed as a function parameter though.. What else should I have said? If something is passed as a parameter to a function it's basic knowledge that it can't be known how that variable is set.. It's in a function for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (to reflect the new question)

If the child `id` is not modified when you handle the `parent` you could get it immediately and then use it to get a new reference.

```
function update(child){
  var id = child.id // Get the id for later
  child.parentNode.innerHTML = child.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(/Stuff/, 'Things');
  child = document.getElementById(id) // Update child reference
  child.innerHTML = 'More stuff again.';
  console.log(child);
}
```

If the `id` is modified, you can just use it to get the `child` again

---

OLD ANSWER

By changing `parent`'s inner HTML the reference to the `child` element is lost.
You could simply update it right after modifying `parent`'s inner HTML.

```
var child  = document.getElementById('child'),
parent = document.getElementById('parent');

// do something with child here

parent.innerHTML = 'Parent ' + parent.innerHTML;
child = document.getElementById('child') // Get new child reference
child.innerHTML = 'More stuff again.';

console.log(child);
```

Comment: What if I have received the element as a function parameter?

Comment: Sorry @JacquesMarais but how do you expect us to give you a decent answer if you keep moving the goal post - give us a complete [mcve] that shows us your complete problem so we can advise you on how to fix it

Comment: @Pete Yes, sorry about that. I didn't think about all these other things that could interfere.

Comment: @Pete That is why I specifically said "remember the element's previous position after updating the parent's `innerHTML`" though.

Comment: @Pete I have updated my question to be more specific, is this better?

Comment: I want to thank you for taking your time to answer this, but if the child is passed as a parameter to a function I wouldn't know which arguments it has

Comment: I think a DOM element in javascript will always have an id parameter. You can check this other question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id#3623125

Comment: Actually it does not, if an `id` attribute isn't specified in the HTML, the DOM object won't have an `id` parameter.

Comment: So check if it does, and if it doesn't set one, so you can find it later.