# elements.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error

`elements.getAttribute is not a function`

I want to get the id value from the first div with help of the name, same with the "a" tag.

```js
function intweb_form() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByName('intweb-button-send');
  var id = elements.getAttribute('id');

  var element = document.getElementsByName("intweb-form-mail-cd");
  var id_code = element.getAttribute('id');
  console.log(id, id_code);
}
```

```html
<div id="mail" name="intweb-form-mail-cd" style="text-align: center;border-radius: 40px; box-shadow: 5px 4px 10px black; background-color: #39CCCC; height: 200px; width: 300px; margin: 0px auto;">
  <p style="padding-top: 15px;font-size:20px; font-weight: bold;">Ihre E-Mail: </p>
  <input id="intweb-ghost-button" type="input" style="padding: 5px"></input>
  <a id="username" name="intweb-button-send" href="javascript:intweb_form()" class="intweb-ghost-button">
    <p style="margin: 0 auto;" id="intweb-ghost-text">Senden</p>
  </a>
```

Comment: Check what `getElementsByName` returns. It's a _collection_ of HTMLElements, not a single element. Try `elements[0].getAttribute()`

Comment: `getElementsByName()` returns a **list** of elements. The list itself does not have the ordinary element APIs; you have to iterate through it like an array.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please do not post PHP if your question is about JavaScript. If you posted the HTML as it was rendered, in a snippet, we could test it quicker. I made you a snippet so you can see how it looks. Feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('intweb-button-send');
```

This will return an array of all the elements with that name.
You are trying to access the attributes of an array. Hence the error.

Comment: This is the right answer, I don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByName() returns a list of elements. You can do getElementsByName(‘intweb-button-send’)[0].id

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions - already answered several times in comments

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.id` property to get the id of an element

```
function intweb_form(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('intweb-button-send');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
         alert(elements[i].id);
    }
```

You should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id)

Comment: Your second statement is still wrong. See comments to the question