# use form id as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My form has an ID:

```
<form id="formname">
```

I wish to use this as a variable in JavaScript.

```
function onSubmit(token) {
   document.getElementById("Formname").submit();
}
```

I have to create a new script for every form with its specific ID in it.

Is there a way to give the script the ID to use as a variable?

like so?

```
const $id = FormId;
function onSubmit(token) {
   document.getElementById($id).submit();
}
```

I´d searched the Internet and only find ways to do it the other way round - to change the ID from javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share more of your code? It is unclear what you want to achieve. Just submitting a form in the `onsubmit` event is rather pointless, because the form is about to be submitted anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/how-can-i-get-an-elements-id-value-with-javascript

Comment: This is an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You think you need to use ID - but perhaps you don't need IDs at all. You should explain the goal and the problem you're facing.

Comment: Does the `name` attribute of the `form` element solve your issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#name

Comment: Almost none of the code that you present in your question makes sense. Like @RokoC.Buljan says, what is it that you would like to achieve? You would like to be able to call `submit()` on more forms, but there could be different, maybe more obvious ways to submit a form, but it depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that my answer fit your need.
Maybe you can try something like this.

```js
function customSubmitFunction(formId){
  // do something
  //...
  //...
  // submit form
  document.getElementById(formId).submit();
}

// when page is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // get all forms with css class managed-form
  document.querySelectorAll('.managed-form').forEach(form => {
    // add event listener to each form
    form.adeventListener('submit', e => {
      // prevent default form submission
      e.preventDefault();
      // get form id
      const formId = e.currentTarget.id;
      // call your custom function
      customSubmitFunction(formId);
    });
  });
});
```

Don't forget to add the css class `managed-form` on your forms.
You will have to remove the "onsubmit" listener on button.

(This code is quite "naive" and can be improved)

(Out of scope, listening click on button to catch form submit event is often not a good solution because a form can also be submitted by pressing "Enter" key)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSubmit(token) {
  let form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[1].id;
   document.getElementById(form).submit();
}
```

This works for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is good, you just have to use lowercase letters in 'formname'.

```
<form id='formname' method='Post' action='file.PHP' 
onsubmit='console.log("Hello 
World")'>
<div name='DivToSend' contenteditable>xxxx</div>
</form>

<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
document.getElementById("formname").submit();
}
</script>
```

Juste write in the contenteditable div and excecute your script another time to see that the action firing, the div will be send to the server file.PHP and console log "Hello World".

You can also use fetch method to send a FormData element.

```
<script>
async function fet(){
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('Name','Value');
const response = await fetch('file.PHP', 
{method:'Post',body:formdata});
const result = await response.text();
console.log(result);
};fet();
</script>
```